# Program to customize a window in Windows (Vista)?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, window-manager

I want a utility that allows me to set a custom opacity for some of my open windows.   Basically, I want to be able to watch movies on VLC while I code, and do other things on my computer. I want the VLC window to float over my other windows, give it an opacity of 50% or so, and make clicks pass through it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to achieve what you want, or at least very very difficult.

Biggest problem:

> Existing applications, even if overridden to be opaque will not allow clicks to pass through them.

Knowing that your other windows will be the ones that require opacity options so you can see VLC behind them. You might find some applications that support this, but most will not, and changing them will be very difficult.

Alternatives:

- Smaller extra monitor off to side, or even < 8" monitors next to keybaord
- Larger monitor TV behind your monitor, say on the wall.

Comment: +1: Opacity isn't the hard part. It is the click passthroughs.